# Defferent hover color in one array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know how can I apply different types of hover condition to different child in one array? Here is my website (http://k29315or.beget.tech/) and I want to make different hover color for every picture on thw main page. Thanks for help!

Comment: It seems like your question is more related to HTML-CSS, you CANT hover arrays :D.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The easiest way, but not the recommended methods is to do it with some CSS customisations ,every block have an unique ID(post id) you can apply style to change hover color example :  `#post-293 .preview-image:after {
    background: red;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, background .3s ease-in-out;
}`

Comment: @ElenaIvinskaya what exactly do you want? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want always different colors, then this can help. If you want to keep the different but same for each box then you have to create an array of colors you want. You can ask, I can create that for you as well. Apologies if this didn't work as per your requirement / expectation.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  
  return color;
}


$('.hover-color').on('mouseover', function () {  
  $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
});
$('.hover-color').on('mouseout', function () {  
  $(this).css('background-color', '');
});
```

```css
.hover-color {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
<div class="hover-color"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let say you have 8 element in your page, create an array with 8 different color code. On hover of element get the index of element and get color code value from array via element index. Apply that color code in element.

Answer (score -2):

First: add different classes to you images. Second: appy your styles.

```css
    .hover_behavior_1:hover { border: 4px solid #000088; }
    .hover_behavior_2:hover { border: 8px solid #555555; }
    .hover_behavior_3:hover { border: 16px solid #990000; }
```

```html
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/6/6d/Ia_scr.jpg" class="hover_behavior_1" />
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/6/6d/Ia_scr.jpg" class="hover_behavior_1" />
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/6/6d/Ia_scr.jpg" class="hover_behavior_2" />
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/6/6d/Ia_scr.jpg" class="hover_behavior_3" />
```

Comment: Please do not encourage questions without a minimal attempt.

Comment: @ElenaIvinskaya , close this question, when you finish : ), someone become angry.
---------
CristianS.  Elena is surely new to the modern web development. And it is very hard and confusing to begin, especially with CSS, HTML, javascript, backend languages and other stuf.

Comment: @A.Denis - Then we should encourage them to do some proper research, go through tutorials and make attempts before just "handing" them the answer. Testing, trying and failing is a big part of the learning curve. Besides, SO's guidelines doesn't differentiate between new and old developers.